# LCM of an N-tuple

Tags: combinatorics

For an $N$-tuple, how to calculate the number of tuples whose LCM is divisible by an integer $d$.

Elements of the tuple are bounded as $1\le a_n\le M$.

I don't know how to proceed after knowing that $\left\lfloor\frac{M}{d}\right\rfloor^N$ tuples are divisible by $d$.

Answer (score 1):

Ongoing Contest question: http://www.codechef.com/JAN15/problems/SEALCM

Please don't answer.

Comment: that's a comment, not an answer

Comment: I cannot comment due to low rep. :)

Comment: Ah 0k :)..not sure what to do xD